# PHP How to trim, trunc, complex data

Tags: php, substring, trim, truncate

This is some data

Case 1 "("2017-02-02 21:15:00",201,1,"E.CO-PUAS KAJANG/AC PANEL ETS",16977.00000)"
Case 2 "("2017-02-02 21:15:00",201,6,"SPARE 6",)"

Im required to extract data without `"(`, to store into 5 variable

```
$date = "2017-02-02 21:15:00";

$code = 201;

$id = 1;

$name = "E.CO-PUAS KAJANG/AC PANEL ETS";

$value = 16977.00000;
```

**Note: SOME CASE like Case 2 return without value and set to 0**

Please show me some example or tips. i found tutorial trim, but it only trim one time

I wanted output will be write like this

```
echo $date;

echo $code;

echo $id;

echo $name;

echo $value;
```

Comment: Read about the following functions: **explode** and **str_replace**. Should be easy after learning those.

Comment: And `trim($str,'()')` for removing the `(` & `)`

Comment: Can your `$name` field feasibly contain commas and/or double quotes? If so, it makes it a little more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying answer to handle data better... plus this looks a lot shorter.

```
$str='("2017-02-02 21:15:00",201,1,"E.CO-PUAS KAJANG/AC PANEL ETS",16977.00000)'; 
$data=trim($str,'()');
$data_array=str_getcsv($data);

$date = $data_array[0];

$code = $data_array[1];

$id = $data_array[2];

$name = $data_array[3];

if($data_array!='')
    $value = $data_array[4];
else
    $value= 0;
```

Comment: Beware the edge cases I mentioned in my comment above. If the `name` field can contain commas, then this algorithm breaks down and you will probably have to resort to using a proper parser.

Comment: hmm. in that case maybe getcsv is the way to go?

Comment: Yeah, [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) should handle most if not all of the potential issues.